# Filter only three characters in shell

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, command

I am trying to parse a command in shell, and in one of the options I want to save in a variable if a string has `"r"`, `"w"`, `"x"`, one of those, all of them, or a mix, but only these three. No other characters should be allowed!

I tried a case where:

```
 $2 in *r*) ;; *w*) ;; *x*) ;; *  ) echo no ;;
esac
```

But in this case if there is written `zr` it will pass, as it has an `"r"`. I only want to make it pass as long as it has one of these three, the three of them, or two of them (any kind of combination), but no other characters.

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you know about regular expressions, [this](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions) seems like it should be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BASH you can use regex for this check like this:

```
re='^[rwx]+$'

s='rw'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

s='zr'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Regex `^[rwx]+$` will allow 1 or more of `r` or `w` or `x` letters.

Comment: The r,w,x are permissions, so in the case that I do not want repetition (as in my program, the user is going to write the permissions, so if it writes " wzr" it will only take the w and the r, but if the user writes "wxx" it will only take the w and x, but not 2 x (no repetition). How could this be done?

Comment: I think that requirement is very different from this question. It will be better if you post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

With extended pattern matching in Bash (`shopt -s extglob`):

```
if [[ $var == +([rwx]) ]]; then
    echo "Matches!"
else
    echo "Does not match!"
fi
```

The `+([rwx])` pattern is "one or more of `r`, `w` or `x`".