# Filter 3 characters (permissions) in bash

Tags: bash, shell

So, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557871/filter-only-three-characters-in-shell) where I wanted to filter only three characters from a String, where the user can write whatever.

> These characters are the ones used for permission purposes: R, W and X.

So in the case the user writes `rwx`, these three letters will be saved in a string.

The order does not matter (if the user writes wxr it will save them anyway).

**Several cases to take into account:**

- If the user writes `zrx`, it will only save in the string the `r` and
  the `x`.
- The user writes more characters, like `zhdghr`, it will only save
  `r`.
- The user writes `rrx`, it will only save one `r` and the `x`. Not
  doubled.

I got this solution but it allows the doubled answer.

```
re='^[rwx]+$'

s='rw'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

s='zr'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Comment: It's the same question, why ask it again ? If the answer on your previous question doesn't match what you expect, you may not accept it. You can still thanks the answerer and upvote his response, and ask him to complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo rrmoewrigowpfovmslfdkmvsx| grep -o "[rwx]"|sort -u|tr -d "\n"
rwx
```

In real world we use octal mode for file permissions which is more easy to parse.

Comment: Thank you! It is just a small program so it will work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to check if the string contains `r`, `w`, or `x` separately. If the string contains `r`, add `r` to the result, etc.

**Example**

```
read -r s

perm=
for p in r w x; do
  [[ "$s" == *"$p"* ]] && perm="${perm}$p"
done

printf '%s\n' "$perm"
```

Comment: Will the "read -w s" and "read -x s" do it with the same loop? Only changing that 1st line?

Comment: @M.K, the `read` builtin function reads one line from the standard input (in particular); `-r` option disables interpretation of backslash as an escape character. The option is commonly used to avoid unexpected behavior due to possible interpretation of some sequences such as `\t`, for example. See `info bash read` for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -o` combined with `awk`:

```
grep -o '[rwx]'<<<"rrx" | awk '!seen[$0]++{} END{for (i in seen) printf "%s", i; print ""}'

xr
```

And

```
grep -o '[rwx]'<<<"zhdghr" | awk '!seen[$0]++{} END{for (i in seen) printf "%s", i; print ""}'

r
```

Or here is a pure awk solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[rwx]$/) !seen[$i]++} END{for (i in seen) printf "%s", i; print ""}' <<< 'zhdghr'

r

awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[rwx]$/) !seen[$i]++} END{for (i in seen) printf "%s", i; print ""}' <<< 'rrx'

xr
```